# Alpha and Beta question [Addmath, quadratic equations]

Tags: beta-function

Please help.

Question: Addmath (Quadratic Equations)

Given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$2x^2 - 6x + 5 = 0$,
form an quadratic equation with the roots $\alpha + 1$ and $\beta + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

To add $1$ to each root, simply shift the function right $1$ unit by replacing $x$ with $x-1$. Then you get
\begin{gather}
2(x-1)^2-6(x-1)+5=0\\
2(x^2-2x+1)-6(x-1)+5=0\\
2x^2-10x+13=0
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 - 3x + \frac 52 = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = x^2 - (\alpha + \beta)x + \alpha \beta$$

Then $\alpha + \beta = 3$ and $\alpha \beta = \frac 52$. So $$(x-(\alpha + 1))(x - (\beta + 1)) = x^2 - (\alpha + \beta+2)x +(\alpha \beta + \alpha + \beta + 1)$$

You should be able to do the rest.